# Chef UFW array merging and priority

Tags: chef-infra, firewall

If I add node level firewall rules do they get merged with the current cookbook rules or do they override them?

For example on our SMTP server if I add a rule to allow port 25, will it merge with the current rules from the cookbooks so it looks like 22, 25,  80, 443, or will it override it completely so only port 25 is allowed>

Thanks, Tim

Comment: what cookbook are you using.  How are you adding port 25? Maually to the file, or through chef's attributes?

Answer (score 0):

You can [read more about attribute precedence](https://docs.chef.io/attributes.html#attribute-precedence) on the Chef site. I'd highly recommend the diagram / visual aid they've created.

In short, the answer to your question is 'it depends.' If you set values using `node.set['foo']='bar'` (recipe syntax) or `normal['foo']=bar` (attribute file syntax), they will completely replace values at, for example, default precedence level -- `node.default['foo']='baz'` (recipe) or 'default['foo']='baz'` (attribute).

The interesting case is what happens when attributes are given at the same precedence level. Noah [has a great post](https://coderanger.net/arrays-and-chef/) on how two arrays behave at the same precedence level (array elements are set-unioned).

If you gave us a specific example of how you're setting attributes for the ufw functionality, we could probably dive deeper into what behavior you'd see, and why.